# How do a{n}? and a{n} differ?

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to understand the following regular expression quantifier (*a* is just an exemplary token here):

```
a{n}?
```

How does the question mark affect the match of the above expression? And how does it differ from the following?

```
a{n}
```

I would have expected the pattern `aa{1}?a` to match both `aaa` and `aa` for example. While it matches `aaa`, `aa` is **not** a match. The pattern `a(a{1})?a` does match both, so the parentheses do make a difference here.

---

Note: The msdn article [Quantifiers in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx) states for both:

> The {n} quantifier matches the preceding element exactly n times,
>   where n is any integer.

For `{n}?`, it adds the following, not overly helpful part:

> It is the lazy counterpart of the greedy quantifier {n}+.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: @AustinHenley may be he means it in context of C# Regex only.

Comment: @AustinHenley Different languages have different Regex flavors. As far as I know, the `{n}?` quantifier is not part of the POSIX standard, so I added the language I'm working with to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: It almost seems like whoever wrote that article wasn't thinking about what they were writing.  How could there be a greedy vs lazy version of *matching exactly n times*?

Comment: @McGarnagle I would understand the thinking behind an *optional* version (match it *either **exactly n times** or **not at all***), which can be expressed by the pattern `a(a{1})?a`. But you're right, what's a greedy, exactly counted match?

Comment: @Mobstaa: Not in regular expressions. You should read the question before commenting or answering. :-)

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Quantifiers > More on the differences..."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Nothing**. The article states:

> The **{n}** quantifier matches the preceding element exactly *n* times, where *n* is any integer. **{*n*}** is a greedy quantifier whose lazy equivalent is **{*n*}?**.
>
> …
>
> The **{n}?** quantifier matches the preceding element exactly *n* times, where *n* is any integer. It is the lazy counterpart of the greedy quantifier **{*n*}+**.

Notice the text is exactly the same. Basically, adding **?** does not change the behavior of the quantifier. It appears that .NET's regular expression engine supports `{n}?` as a alternative to `{n}`.

---

Interestingly, this article does appear to contain an error:

> The **{*n*,}** quantifier matches the preceding element at least *n* times, where *n* is any integer. **{*n,*}** is a greedy quantifier whose lazy equivalent is **{*n*}?**.

This is wrong. The lazy equivalent of `{n,}` is `{n,}?` which is *not* the same as `{n}?`.

**UPDATE: Newer version of the article have corrected this error.**

Comment: So it seems the version with the question mark (`{n}?`) is only implemented (and documented) for completeness because its siblings `{n,}?` and `{n,m}?` also exist?

Comment: @MariusSchulz Yes, I'd say so. The article even provides an example using `{n}?` but that code behaves identically if you replace it with `{n}`.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have `{n}?` problems.

Comment: "only implemented (and documented) for completeness" -- no, it's the other way around ... the spec and the implementation would have to go out of the way to exclude {...}? in the case where there's an exact count, and there's no reason to do that and plenty of reasons not to.

Comment: "It is the lazy counterpart of the greedy quantifier {n}+" -- that was an error (in implementations that support it, {n}+ is possessive, not merely greedy) but the documentation has been changed and no longer says that.

Answer (score 1):

More a notice than an answer, but good to know, in particular if you project to use a same pattern in different languages or if you decide to use an other regex library with .net.

About:

> I would have expected the pattern `aa{1}?a` to match both `aaa` and `aa` for example. While it matches `aaa`, `aa` is not a match.

`a{n}` and `a{n}?` produce the same result (there are seen as the greedy and non-greedy version, but of a fixed quantifier) with most of the regex engines.

But this is **not** the case with Oniguruma and Onigmo regex engines. With them `a{n}?` behaves like `(?:a{n})?`.
Since wrappers for .net exist for these libraries, it is useful to clarify.

The same with ERE (Extended Regular Expressions) used in sed, grep and with dbms.